# How to create a robust pattern to add dynamic and generic components to JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I have a webapp which is highly parametrable and dynamic. I use JSF 2 with Mojarra 2.1.19 and Primefaces 3.5.

By component I mean a high level component: A backbean associated to a xhtml file. The backed bean inside the xhtml template has always the EL name "comp".

The features I have implemented are the following :

- I have a container component (a tab, a panel..), and I want to be able to render any components inside it. The container is fed dynamicly through user actions and configuration files with no way to predict which and how many components will contain the container.
- A component "A" can refresh a component "B" whatever is position in the components tree and without hard coupling. Component "A" do not know component "B", component "A" only knows that it needs to refresh the feature implemented by component "B".

With the component pattern I can construct high level application with a components tree. I actually use the c:forEach pattern to dynamicly adds component :

```
<c:forEach items="#{comp.values}" var="value">
    <ui:include src="#{value.uri}">
        <ui:param name="comp" value="#{value}"/>
    </ui:include>
</c:forEach>
```

I use generic channel message to link components. To refresh I use binding

I have read that all the following patterns can create inconsistent state and throw the feared duplicate Id exception :

- c:forEach
- binding on session
- adding component through java

I always have the feeling of walking on a minefield. Now I'm stuck with a nasty duplicate id error.

Is there a way to create a robust pattern to add dynamic and generic components to JSF 2 ?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you aren't binding physically different components to one and same bean property across the view scope. The `binding` attribute must point a request scoped property and absolutely not be shared across physically different components during the view scope, even though it's used by at most one component at the same time.

The problem "binding on session" is only applicable if you bind an unique component to a session scoped bean property, but open the same view multiple times in different browser tabs/windows in the same session.

Comment: I'm follow theses rules but I'm stuck with JSF issue : same template used more than once, your well documented "Ajax rendering of content which contains another form", c:forEach which create inconsistent state and so on. I am desperate to find a robust solution.

Comment: Maybe the salvation will come from JSF 2.2

Comment: Just stop sharing the property behind `binding` attribute by physically different components. If you want dynamicness, just use e.g. an array or map.

Comment: I do not share the property behind binding (all components are loosely coupled) and I have set as request attribute all my binding.